# SiteEdit tag information is not coming in Page

Tags: web8, experience-manager, siteedit

We have upgraded from SDL Tridion 2013 to SDL Web 8, after publishing a Page from Tridion we have got the following information in the Page:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="SiteEditSettings" runat="server">
    <!--SITE_EDIT_INIT-->
</asp:Content>
```

On the Page, the XPM button is not visible.

I have configured Session and Preview service already in CD side. What is the issue here?

Comment: Can you **edit** your question and supply a bit more detail like what type of Templating model you use, if you have migrated to the new publishing model in Web 8 etc.?

Comment: Definitely i will give information but what do you mean by Templating model.Previously we have used target types for xpm but now after migrating to web8 we have used discovery service and toplogy manger for publishing.

Comment: Also when i preview the page i can see Site edit tag with all relevant information from CM side but only after publishing on CD side the those information is missing.though sitedit tag is available.

Comment: I meant, what type of Templates do you use, is it Modular Templating with DWT TBBs, Razor Templating or perhaps something of DD4T or DXA? Since you mentioned you have moved to the new Publishing Model with Topology Manager, are you certain that is correctly setup for XPM too?